# AHK (Binding keys)

Tags: cygwin, autohotkey, key-binding

I'm trying to bind the following keys.

I want to be able to use Shift+LeftArrow to navigate between two windows. 
Since I mainly use these two windows in one monitor It would be great to move between them.

Currently you can do this by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Tab. However I want to use AHK to bind that feature to Shift + Left Arrow

I've tried the following, but keep in mind I'm not too good at this. 
^Win+LeftArrow:: RCtrlShiftTab

All help is greatly appreciated.

Update: ^Left:: RCtrl^Tab (Error it says is it doesn't recognize RCtrl^Tab)

Comment: First, I think `LeftArrow` should just be `Left`. That being said, are you trying to map Ctrl,Win,Shift,Left to RCtrl,Shift,Tab? (`+` maps to Shift)

Comment: I want to map ShiftLeftArrow or ShiftLeft to Ctrl+Shift+Tab

Comment: Is the Cygwin tag really appropriate?

Comment: That's the program the key binding is for, thought maybe someone has made some to switch windows they can simply share and I can modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do:

`+Left::Send {RCtrl down}+{Tab}{RCtrl up}`

Comment: At first I didn't notice only `RCtrl` was required to be bound

Comment: I wish I could understand it the way you do but it works and that's all that matters. <3 

highly appreciated.

If you don't mind sharing an explanation of the lines I would also appreciate it.

Comment: Plus sign, as cricket_007 pointed out, is mapped to Shift. `Send` function sends keys. :-) RCtrl needs to be pressed *down* while you are ShiftTab-ing to switch windows, then released (*up*)

Comment: Yep lol I re-read it over and over and found some articles. - Actually just did another one I wanted to use for  Cygwin..